# What happens to message in a Kafka consumer read timeout scenario in AggregatingReplyingKafkaTemplat?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I have a working implementation where I am using one producer topic and getting responses for request  from two consumer topics.

In some scenarios ,out of the two responses one of the response is timing out and since I have below configuration I am continuing with my one response.

**returnPartialOnTimeout = true**

I have a requirement to cater where in case of timeout scenario for one of the response message , I want to find out the details about the message which has timed out.

Is there a way to get any details about the message ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you mean; you can tell from the partial reply which consumer replied and which one did not.

If you mean you need to handle the situation when the other consumer replies, but after the timeout:

You can subclass the template and override `logLateArrival()`.

Here is the default implementation:

```java
protected void logLateArrival(ConsumerRecord<K, R> record, Object correlationId) {
    if (this.sharedReplyTopic) {
        this.logger.debug(() -> missingCorrelationLogMessage(record, correlationId));
    }
    else {
        this.logger.error(() -> missingCorrelationLogMessage(record, correlationId));
    }
}
```